How stop bash from setting default terminal window title
All I find with google is how to set a window title, but that's not the problem - I know how to do that, the problem is that after every command, the title is getting reset to the default and I can't find where that's happening to stop it. Hopefully someone here can point me to the offending location... Thanks!

Please [edit] your question and tell us how you are setting the title. once we know how you are changing it, and in which file you have added the command to change it, we can try and figure out what might be changing it back. Ideally, you should give us enough detail so we can reproduce the behavior you are observing in order to test out answers.

The default .bashrc that ships with Ubuntu sets the prompt (PS1) and title of the gnome-terminal. Therefore you need to change environment variable PS1 otherwise your changes won't show up because it will reset the title after each command.
First make a copy of you .bashrc  (in your $HOME directory) in case you make a mistake and you can move it back easily.
Use your favorite editor to edit your .bashrc. (I use vi)
Search for PS1 (/ in vi)
Below this you will see a case: -
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)

Below you will see a line of code as follows: -
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"

Which you should comment out (start with #) and copy and modify to
PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:$"


To make it easy to change the title you can also create a function below the above function - the line after esac (end of case). Then insert the following function: -
#To set terminal name
set_term_title(){
   echo -en "\033]0;$1\a"
}


Then save and exit the editor.
Run the script as follows: -
source .bashrc

From the prompt start the function name and press tab to complete and add a text name after and return. You should see your gnome-terminal name change.
Good luck
I hope this was of some help.

Sorry, I have the PS1 variable already set to something else, that's not what's doing it...

After digging around, I found it was __vte_prompt_command() in /etc/profile.d/vte-2.91.sh, which PROMPT_COMMAND was getting set to. I unset PROMPT_COMMAND in my startup files, and it fixed the problem.
